# Hold and print a generated math expression

Tags: front-end, evaluation, output-formatting, notebooks, formatting

I have written a function `myPfuntest`,

```
myPfuntest[layer_] := 
    Table[{-1, 1} /. 
        Abs[GroupBy[CoefficientList[
        Nest[x*D[#, x] &, Product[1 - x^(2^i), {i, 0, layer}], level]
        ,x], Sign]], {level, 1, layer}
]

myPfuntest[1] // MatrixForm
myPfuntest[2] // MatrixForm
myPfuntest[3] // MatrixForm
myPfuntest[4] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Hoping to get this kind of desired result

$1+2 = 3$

and

$
\begin{aligned}
1+2+4+7 &= 3+5+6 \\
1^2+2^2+4^2+7^2&= 3^2+5^2+6^2
\end{aligned}
$

and

$
\begin{aligned}
 1+2+4+7+8+11+13+14  &=  3+5+6+9+10+12+15 \\
 1^2+2^2+4^2+7^2+8^2+11^2+13^2+14^2  &=  3^2+5^2+6^2+9^2+10^2+12^2+15^2 \\
 1^3+2^3+4^3+7^3+8^3+11^3+13^3+14^3  &=  3^3+5^3+6^3+9^3+10^3+12^3+15^3
\end{aligned}
$

I can use `Sqrt[]`, [`CubeRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CubeRoot.html) and [`Surd`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Surd.html) to get the base numbers, or simplify format them based on the linear sets, but how to I keep them from evaluating? For example

```
{1, 2, 4, 7}^2
```

would not give me

> {1^2,2^2,4^2,7^2}

Comment: What is the official name for these kind of equations? I wish to read more about the underlying math.

Comment: @magma I got this from a question I was doing. I actually have no idea about the names, and I was hoping someone here would give a bit more on the underlying maths too as it's really interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, we can play with boxes:

```
Clear@helper;

helper[a_List] := helper /@ a // Column; 

helper[{a_?VectorQ, b_}] := 
 HoldForm @@ 
  MakeExpression@
   RowBox[Join[#, {"="}, #2] & @@ (lst |-> 
        Riffle[SuperscriptBox[#, 2] & /@ lst, "+"]) /@ {a, b}]

helper@myPfuntest[2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Defer` also:

```
powersum // ClearAll;
powersum[n_] := Apply[Plus, Defer /@ Surd[#, n]^n] &;

myPfuntest[layer_] := 
  Table[{-1, 1} /. 
      Abs[
       GroupBy[
        CoefficientList[
         Nest[x*D[#, x] &, Product[1 - x^(2^i), {i, 0, layer}], 
          level], x], Sign]] //
     Map@powersum@level // Apply@Equal, (* N.B. *)
   {level, 1, layer}];
```

[image]

`HoldForm` works in place of `Defer` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HoldForm`, which prints expression maintained in unevaluated form, and the fact that substitution works in held expressions:

```
HoldForm[1 + 2 + 3 = 3 + 2 + 1]
```

[image]

```
HoldForm[a = b] /. { 
  a -> Plus @@ (HoldForm[#]^2 & /@ {1, 2, 4, 7}),
  b -> Plus @@ (HoldForm[#]^2 & /@ {3, 5, 6})}
```

[image]